# How to connect to a database on mysql workbench on local host?

Tags: mysql, localhost, mysql-workbench

I'm having issues in connecting the database to my local host using mysql workbench.

Comment: Please add some specific details , what problem you are facing?

Comment: it is displaying an error message stating that access is denied for user using password

Answer (score 0):

1. Put `127.0.0.1` as your host
2. `3306` should be the default port using by MySQL
3. If needed, try also to put your default database

It's actually pretty simple, I don't know what to add

Comment: Shouldn't you put localhost as your host?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 and localhost are the same. Localhost is an alias linking to 127.0.0.1